# Powershell List every thing not in something else

Tags: powershell

The purpose of this script is to pull all employee IDs from AD, then check them against all employee IDs in SQL. Every employee ID that does not exist in SQL is the intended output.

```
import-module activedirectory
$sqlpeeps = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '192.168.1.1' -Database 'COMPANY' -Query "SELECT EmployeeID FROM [COMPANY].[dbo].[employee] WHERE [COMPANY].[dbo].[employee].[EmployeeStatus] in ('A', 'S', 'L')"
$adpeeps = get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "OU=OU,OU=OU,OU=OU,DC=DC,DC=COM" -properties 'EmployeeID'

$adpeeps | where-object { $_ -notin $sqlpeeps} | out-host
```

What I have now seems to output all employee IDs

Answer (score 1):

`$adpeeps` is a list of AD user objects, but `$sqlpeeps` are EmployeeIDs, so change it to:

```
$adpeeps | Where-Object { $_.EmployeeID -and ($_.EmployeeID -notin $sqlpeeps) }
```

Comment: OK update! I have a list of employeeIDs being output, but there seems like everything that came up false is showing as a blank line, so there is a list with tons of blank spaces. Is there an easy way to clean those up?

Comment: Updated the answer. Is that what you mean?